# the while loop does not stop even when the component is unmounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I used `while` loop for polling the API response, inside a modal.

The problem is that this while loop is not being aborted even when the modal is closed.

Please check the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/polling-not-aborted-vnq0ey) to see actual code running.

In the sandbox above, you'll see the console.log keeps running even when you close the modal.

I expected that the while loop will be aborted since the modal is being conditionally rendered, and it should be unmounted if it's not being rendered.

can anyone explain why the while loop is alive?

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Modal = () => {
  const wait = async (ms = 1000) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  };

  let count = 0;
  const pollIncrement = async () => {
    while (count < 100) {
      await wait(2000);
      console.log(++count);
    }
    return count;
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    pollIncrement();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        background: "blue",
        color: "white",
        width: "400px",
        height: "400px"
      }}
    >
      {count}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setIsModalOpen(!isModalOpen)}>open modal</button>
      {isModalOpen && <Modal />}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: It’s just a function, running functions don’t stop running if their parent context changes or goes away. For any async React effect you need to handle the effect finishing after the component unmounts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your useEffect may optionally return a cleanup function.
When you unmount the Modal, React does not automatically terminate the executing code for you. You need to handle this issue manually.

```js
const Modal = () => {
  const wait = async (ms = 1000) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  };

  let count = 0;
  const mounted = React.useRef(false)
  const pollIncrement = async () => {
    while (count < 100 && mounted.current) {
      await wait(2000);
      console.log(++count);
    }
    return count;
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    mounted.curren t= true
    pollIncrement();
    return ()=>{mounted.current = false}
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        background: "blue",
        color: "white",
        width: "400px",
        height: "400px"
      }}
    >
      {count}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: wow it obviously works. I wonder why using useState does not solve the problem, while useRef works. Thank you for the solution!

Comment: React does not interrupt executing js code when Modal is destroyed

Answer (score 0):

To come out of the while loop, you try to use endloop; if it doesn't work, if name is empty, other statements will not execute, and the entire loop will shut down.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can consider setInterval as it might be more suited for you are trying to achieve.

```
const intervalId = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  // doWork is function containing logic you want executed every 2 seconds
  intervalId.current = setInterval(doWork, 2000);

  return () => { 
    clearInterval(intervalId.current); 
  }
}, [])
```

Function you return from the useEffect will be executed when component unmounts, making it convenient for cleanup work, such as stopping/canceling running jobs.